# Proxy to single host

Tags: proxy

Im looking for a way to proxy traffic to one host thru proxy.
I know that default proxy in Ubuntu got exclusions list - but im looking for a way to get inclusions list (I need to use proxy just for one host/ip - I don't want to include all traffic through the proxy because I want low latency to the other addresses I use for my project.)

For my studies project I got a VPS... and unfortunately the ip of this VPS is on blacklist so I get 403 error when trying to get to one web page that I need.

I will be grateful for advice on how to deal with this problem.
Im looking for a global-system wide sollution - that will work thru browser/terminal etc.

On my VPS I use Ubuntu 22.

Comment: Which type of connections are you talking about? Web? SSH? Any TCP/UDP connection?

Comment: Only need it for web

Comment: You can use browser add-ons. I use ***Proxy SwitchyOmega*** for example.

Comment: Thats what I use now - But im looking for a system wide fix